# File creating permission Denied

Tags: 14.04, filesystem, makefile

I have removed Windows 7 and installed Ubuntu 14.04.

I have successfully installed LAMP but the problem is that I cannot save a file with a PHP extension in `local-server` using the Bluefish editor .

The error message is "Permission denied"

Can anyone help.

Comment: @letizia: I think he just doesn't know what `sudo` is, and needs some explaining...

Comment: Yes, @Fabby, I suggested that link, because there is a useful answer that explains in detail how to work on /var/www. I proposed it as dupe for this reason. edwardtorwalds has given a quick good answer and OP has accepted it, this is okey too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get permission to read/write in `/var/www` folder:

```
sudo adduser <username> www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+rw /var/www
```

here replace `<username>` with your username.