# Apache2 403 Forbidden - you don't have permission to access

Tags: permissions, apache2, apache2.4, www

I've added one virtual host to `sites-available`. It was showing `Index Of...` a while ago, then I installed mysql, don't know if it's the reason but after that there was 404, then I changed `Directory`to `/var/www/html/` and is now showing 403.

I'ver tried `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www` with no avail.
Also changed `DocumentRoot` in `000-defaut.conf` to `/var/www/html/`.
There're never any errors in `error.log`.

It's a vps and i'm accessing it via ssh

Comment: 403 from browser, how'll that help? Though i just tried that, nothing

Comment: try in the sequence shown by this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/554940/294611

Comment: Sorry, but still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We eventually found that is a misconfiguration between 00-default and mysite.com.

I guess that request are serverd by mysite.com VirtualHost that have not permission to access `/var/www/html`.

If you need both `VirtualHost` working, Apache need to recognize both either by name or by ip.

You should add `ServerName` directive in 00-default and add both name in /etc/hosts as described in [How to access a website under Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509547/how-to-access-a-website-under-ubuntu)

Also don't forget that 404 error means "not found", when you change `DocumentRoot`, you should move file to the new directory too.